# Find string in URL - joomla/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a "simple" problem that I can't get my head around, I want to search my URL, and find either `/nl/` or `/en/` or `/fr/` and add a class to the body accordingly.

I've searched high and low and can't seem to find the right answer.

The URL is build "cleanly', so it reads: `www.mysite.com/nl/mypage`.

Comment: Why not assign that value to a variable with your server-side language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like -

```
if (location.href.indexOf('/en/') > -1) {
    $("body").addClass("enClass");
}
```

Comment: This did the trick!! Thanks you very much!

I'm just going to apply a switch statement to it and I'm done! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = 'www.mysite.com/nl/mypage...';
$url_parts = explode('/', $url);

foreach($url_parts as $part):
if($part = 'nl'){ var_dump($part); }
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. Capture the URL as a variable:

```
var url = window.location;
```

Then search for the languages:

```
var pattern = /\/en\/|\/nl\/|\/fr\//
if (url.match(pattern)) {
  // there's a match
} else {
  // there isn't
}
```

If you want to do an `if` statement for just one language, change the pattern to only include that one language. For example, `en`:

```
var pattern = /\/en\//;
if (url.match(pattern)) {
  // on en
} else {
  // not on en
}
```